# Is it possible to restore default viewport condition?

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

This is default viewport condition after I made a '2d animation' project by ctrl+n.

[image]

And I scrolled mouse-middle button to zoom out viewport.

Then I wanted to restore default viewport condition(not similar but exactly same as first picture ) but I could not.

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/217779/110840

Comment: @allen simpson Your answer is very good. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Default Viewport Reset]

File>Defaults>Load Factory Settings. This will reset everything, like your addons, custom startup file too.

Comment: Then do not all things I have drawn disappear? I want only default viewport condition not new project.

Comment: @나미손 They will not disappear. This is different from loading a new project.