# How do I remove all these windows?

Tags: interface, windows

[image]

I accidently puted these windows. How do I get rid of these?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/129387/how-to-close-windows-in-2-8

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/217766/id-like-to-move-the-3d-viewport-back-to-its-starting-position/217779#217779

Comment: Hi, artiom. and welcome.. it does appear that there are other answers to this question in the archive that should be enough to solve your problem. If not, explain, and we can re-open.

Answer (score 1):

1. Move your mouse cursor over the corner of an area.
2. Press and **hold** $\color{green}{█}\color{#888}{0█}$ *left mouse button*.
3. Drag your mouse to the surrounding area.
4. Release the mouse button.

[image]

Comment: Now how to open back scene window? (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkhfh.jpg)

Comment: @artiomligay check the links provided by Allen Simpson.